# Getting last 24 hours from current time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure why the dateadd function is not working here.  I am trying to pull only the last 24 hours from current time but i see hours like 3-6 pm of today's date.  the data type is datetime but i am not sure what is going on here.

```
select Name, location, myDate from myTable where myDate >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

when i run the query above the outcome will include this:

```
2015-03-05 15:00:00.000
2015-03-05 15:30:00.000
2015-03-05 16:00:00.000
2015-03-05 16:30:00.000
2015-03-05 17:00:00.000
2015-03-05 17:30:00.000
2015-03-05 18:00:00.000
2015-03-05 18:30:00.000
2015-03-05 19:00:00.000
2015-03-05 19:30:00.000
2015-03-05 20:00:00.000
2015-03-05 20:30:00.000
2015-03-05 21:00:00.000
2015-03-05 21:30:00.000
2015-03-05 22:00:00.000
2015-03-05 22:30:00.000
2015-03-05 23:00:00.000
2015-03-05 23:30:00.000
```

I was expecting not to see these hours at all.

Comment: Your query seeks all rows where `myDate >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())`. That would include tomorrow, next week, and next year. Is that the issue you wish to address? Note that providing an example of "incorrect" output without the corresponding inputs isn't very helpful.

Comment: you're missing `and myDate <= GETDATE()  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BETWEEN, ie

```
select Name, location, myDate from myTable where myDate between DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

This `myDate >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())` gets you all records where myDate is greater than 24 hours ago, including records that have future dates(if they are correct to have future dates is another story...)