# Delete all data except for the last 2 days using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete all data from my table except the last 2 days; also deleting today's data.

```
delete from myTable where myDate > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, -2, GETDATE()), -2)
```

this is not working for me
sample data

```
2015-03-06 18:00:00.000
2015-03-06 18:30:00.000
2015-03-06 19:00:00.000
2015-03-06 19:30:00.000
2015-03-06 20:00:00.000
2015-03-06 20:30:00.000
2015-03-06 21:00:00.000
2015-03-06 21:30:00.000
2015-03-06 22:00:00.000
2015-03-06 22:30:00.000
2015-03-06 23:00:00.000
2015-03-06 23:30:00.000
2015-03-05 00:00:00.000
2015-03-05 00:30:00.000
```

Comment: Looks a lot like your previous questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884686/getting-last-24-hours-from-current-time-in-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882878/how-to-get-last-24-hours-from-current-timestamp-in-sql -- isn't 2 days then just 48 hours vs 24 hours?

Comment: You want to delete today's data also or only previous data except last 2 days?

Comment: yes i want to delete today's data too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. You were pretty close. What you want is the start of today minus 2 days, as below. Also, you were using the greater than operator (>) instead of the less than (<), which would have deleted everything in the last two days, but not before.

```
delete from myTable 
where myDate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply recommend:

```
delete
    from myTable
    where myDate > cast(getdate() - 2 as date);
```

This will work in SQL Server 2008+.